# Monthly record count in laravel and print to javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to create count monthly data using bar chart in laravel,,

```
$monthly_assessment = DB::table('praapplication')
         ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as total'), DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))
         ->where('stage', 'W1')
         ->groupBy('month')
         ->get();
```

the output like this i get:

```
total:2, month:10 ; total:3, month:11
```

the output of code should be like this to represented in Javascript

```
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0]
```

how to parse in Javascript

```
name: 'Submission',
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i usually do is..

```
$list = [];
// loop all 12 month
foreach(range(1, 12) as $month) {
   $flag = false; // init flag if no month found in montly assessment
   foreach($monthly_assessment as $data) {
      if ($data->month == $month) { // if found add to the list
          $list [] = $data->count;
          $flag = true;
          break; // break the loop once it found match result
      }
   }

   if(!$flag) {
      $list [] = 0; // if not found, store as 0
   }
}
return $data = [
    'name' : 'Submission',
    'data' : $list
];
```

Output:

```
{
    name: 'Submission',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0]
}
```

Comment: how can i use in blade laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Return your data like this.

```
$monthly_assessment = DB::table('praapplication')
         ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as total'), DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))
         ->where('stage', 'W1')
         ->groupBy('month')
         ->get();

return response()->json($monthly_assessment , 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: no because i use many return in view                                                                                                          return view('adminpage.dashboard', compact('monthly_assessment','praaplication', 'count_submission','announc','count','bestmajikan','bestagentmonth','bestagentyears', 'countsub',));